# spss counting first consecutive zeros across variables

Tags: count, rows, spss, distinct-values

I want to count the days when a subject did not receive treatment (a "0" in my file. If a subject did receive treatment it is denoted with "1". Subject can get multiple  courses of treatments and I would like to count the days between the first and second treatment. I am not (yet) interested in the time between the second and third treatment. 
Basically my spss file looks like this:

`id` `day1` `day2` `day3` `day4` `day28`
`A`--- `1`-----`0`-----`0`----`1`------`0`
`B`--- `1`---- `0`-----`1`----`0`------`1`
`C`---`etc`

I am only interested in the first series of zeros. The output I hope to get is:

`id` `first_series_zero`
`A` `2`
`B` `1`
`C` `...`

Can anyone help my out, here. Obviously, just counting all the zeros isn't going to work, because there might be multiple sets of zeroes in one row.

Cheers, Dylan

Comment: What's the code that you currently have?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one pretty general approach that will allow you to calculate the times between all of the different treatments. First I create a vector that stores the locations of all of the treatments, `Loc1 TO Loc5` (using `day1` to `day5` as an example).

```
DATA LIST FREE / day1 day2 day3 day4 day5.
BEGIN DATA
1 0 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
END DATA.

VECTOR day = day1 TO day5.
VECTOR Loc(5,F2.0).
COMPUTE #id = 1.
LOOP #i = 1 TO 5.
  DO IF day(#i) = 1.
    COMPUTE Loc(#id) = #i.
    COMPUTE #id = #id + 1.
  END IF.
END LOOP.
```

Now if you run this transformation, the `Loc` vector will look like this for this example data.

```
Loc1 Loc2 Loc3 Loc4 Loc5 

  1    4    .    .    . 
  1    3    5    .    .
```

Now to calculate the difference for the first series is as simple as:

```
COMPUTE first_series_zero = Loc2 - Loc1 - 1.
```

This will return missing if there is never a second (or first) treatment, and is not dependent on `day1` always being the first day of the treatment. Now to calculate the difference between all of the treatments is quite simple, and here is a `DO REPEAT` approach.

```
VECTOR DifS(4,F2.0).
DO REPEAT F = Loc1 TO Loc4 /B = Loc2 TO Loc5 /D = DifS1 TO DifS4.
  COMPUTE D = B - F - 1.
END REPEAT.
```

And so `DifS1` would be the zeroes between the 1st and 2nd treatment, `DifS2` would be the zeroes between the 2nd and 3rd treatment etc. (Both this do repeat and the first loop could be made more efficient with a loop that only goes over valid/possible values.)